# How can I center this timeline code on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to implement this code on my website but am having trouble getting the timeline centered on mobile devices. When running the code I am able to get everything how I want but once I load it up on mobile it is unreadable.

I have tried changing the positioning but no luck yet.

The code stays centered on web and tablets but not an iphones or androids.

```css
:root {
  --primary-color: #212121;
  --background-color: #111;
  --font: sans-serif;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: var(--background-color);
  font-family: var(--font);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* Timeline Container */
.timeline {
  background: var(--primary-color);
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* Card container */
.card {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 400px;
}

/* setting padding based on even or odd */
.card:nth-child(odd) {
  padding: 30px 0 30px 30px;
}
.card:nth-child(even) {
  padding: 30px 30px 30px 0;
}
/* Global ::before */
.card::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  border: solid orangered;
}

/* Setting the border of top, bottom, left */
.card:nth-child(odd)::before {
  left: 0px;
  top: -4.5px;
  bottom: -4.5px;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-radius: 50px 0 0 50px;
}

/* Setting the top and bottom to "-5px" because earlier it was out of a pixel in mobile devices */
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .card:nth-child(odd)::before {
    top: -5px;
    bottom: -5px;
  }
}

/* Setting the border of top, bottom, right */
.card:nth-child(even)::before {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border-width: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  border-radius: 0 50px 50px 0;
}

/* Removing the border if it is the first card */
.card:first-child::before {
  border-top: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
}

/* Removing the border if it is the last card  and it's odd */
.card:last-child:nth-child(odd)::before {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}

/* Removing the border if it is the last card  and it's even */
.card:last-child:nth-child(even)::before {
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}

/* Information about the timeline */
.info {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #333;
  color: gray;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* Title of the card */
.title {
  color: orangered;
  position: relative;
}

/* Timeline dot  */
.title::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 999px;
  border: 3px solid orangered;
}

/* text right if the card is even  */
.card:nth-child(even) > .info > .title {
  text-align: right;
}

/* setting dot to the left if the card is odd */
.card:nth-child(odd) > .info > .title::before {
  left: -45px;
}

/* setting dot to the right if the card is odd */
.card:nth-child(even) > .info > .title::before {
  right: -45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="info">
        <h3 class="title">Title 1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="info">
        <h3 class="title">Title 2</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="info">
        <h3 class="title">Title 3</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="info">
        <h3 class="title">Title 4</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="info">
        <h3 class="title">Title 5</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Everything looks normal in the code snippet. Can you share all the code inside the `<html></html>` element? The question doesn't seem clear as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for this to correct the scaling on mobile

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand much about it, but it seems that you need to use some specific media queries.

The ones I'm using mostly are:

```
@media (max-width: 675px)
{}
```

Hope I was able to help! Happy Coding!